Finding the differences then copy and paste code to a new sheet
I've been trying to write this VBA code to automate the process of finding differences between 2 original source sheets and then copying the entire row of the differences into a new sheet.
the process should be like this:

The code should look into Column A for both source sheets, finding only the right value to start the comparison, for example: InStr(cell1.Value, "1") > 0
after that, the code should look into column B for the actual differences. if the code finds a difference, then it would then copy the entire row where that different value is in. for example: the differences is in B2 in sheet A and B3 in sheet B, then it would copy the entire row 2 from sheet A and row 3 from sheet B to the new sheet
When the code paste to a new sheet, it should paste the rows from sheet A at from the first column, and rows from sheet B to 3 columns after the end columns of sheet A. for example: Since both source sheet has the same amount of columns, so when pasting sheet A to the new sheet, it should be from Column A to AJ, then pasting rows from sheet B should paste into the new sheet from Column AN to BW, leaving AJ, AK and AL free

Here is the code that I've tried to make so far. Do note that I have not add all feature i wanted because I've been getting errors from the result.
Sub GetLevel1Difference()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim maxCols As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    ' Set the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your first sheet name
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2") ' Change "Sheet2" to your second sheet name
    
    Set col1 = ws1.Range("A:A")
    Set col2 = ws2.Range("A:A")
    
    
    ' Create a new worksheet for results
    Set wsResult = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ComparisonResult") 

    ' Get the last used row in columns of both sheets
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, col1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, col2.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Get the maximum columns used in ws1
    maxCols = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 3
    
    ' Initialize the result row counter
    resultRow = 2
    
    ' Loop through each row in the first sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow1
        ' Find matching row in the second sheet
        For j = 2 To lastRow2
        
            Set cell1 = col1.Cells(i, 1)
            Set cell2 = col2.Cells(j, 1)
            
            ' Compare values in the specified column
            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value And InStr(cell1.Value, "1") > 0 And InStr(cell2.Value, "1") > 0 Then
            
                ' Define the range for the row to copy from ws1
                Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                
                ' Define the range for the row to copy from ws2
                Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, 1), ws2.Cells(j, ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                
                 ' Copy the entire row from the first sheet to the result sheet
                rng1.Copy
                wsResult.Cells(resultRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ' Copy the entire row from the second sheet to the result sheet, offset by maxCols
                rng2.Copy
                wsResult.Cells(resultRow, maxCols).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
                ' Increment the result row counter
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    MsgBox "Comparison and copy completed!", vbInformation

End Sub

The code does what it should do for the 1st sheet, finding the right value for Column A then pasting it to the new sheet at the right location.
However, For the second sheet, it copy the same values from the first result it found and then pasting it all repeatedly until it matched the amount of result from the first sheet. It should be noted that the 2 sheets have a different amount of rows.
Here is the result from my own excel page. some columns has been hidden for readability, but the 2nd part constantly repeat itself:


Try this out:
Sub GetLevel1Difference()
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, i As Long
    Dim resultRow As Long, maxCols As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, v1, m
    
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your first sheet name
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 2") ' Change "Sheet2" to your second sheet name
    Set wsResult = wb.Worksheets("ComparisonResult") ' Create a new worksheet for results
    
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    maxCols = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' Get the maximum columns used in ws1
    
    resultRow = 2 ' Initialize the result row counter
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow1              ' Loop through each row in the first sheet
        v1 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value   ' ColA value
        If InStr(v1, "1") > 0 Then     ' contains "1" ?
            m = Application.Match(v1, ws2.Columns("A"), 0) 'find exact value on sheet2 ColA
            If Not IsError(m) Then                         'got match? m is the matched row number
                If ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value <> ws2.Cells(m, "B").Value Then 'colB values different?
                    'copy sheet1 values
                    wsResult.Cells(resultRow, "A").Resize(1, maxCols).Value = _
                                        ws1.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, maxCols).Value
                    'copy sheet2 matched row values
                    wsResult.Cells(resultRow, maxCols + 3).Resize(1, maxCols).Value = _
                                        ws2.Cells(m, 1).Resize(1, maxCols).Value
                    resultRow = resultRow + 1
                End If   ' colB values are different
            End If   'got a match on Col A
        End If   'contains "1"
    Next i
    MsgBox "Comparison and copy completed!", vbInformation

End Sub


Thank you for replying with an answer, However, I tried it on my current workbook with the changed Parameters, it was still printing the 2nd half repeatedly. I tried it with a completely new workbook, with the 2 original sheets i needed copied over, and it still print the 2nd half repeatedly. If you could please help me again with this issue.

Your screenshots don't match your description of what you want to do - your code is matching values in ColA which contain "1", but those values all seem to be the same?

Sorry that I could not make it clear, here's the example book that i've just created. I've been trying to compare column A between both of the source sheets, then if the level match each other(level 1), then they will compare Column E in both source. the end result should only have the difference between the 2 sheet. I've also included what a result should look like.

The "should be" result in your workbook doesn't match your description.  There no colE = 965-208382-001 on sheet 1 for level 1

Ok this is very confusing, I will clarify what I wanted to do again. So I wanted to compare between sheet 1 and sheet 2. If Column A in both Sheets contain the number 1(level 1), the code will then compare the Part number(Column E) between all the level 1, and if it spots any that is different, then will copy those results entire row to the new ComparisonResult sheet.

Yes that's what you said before, but it doesn't explain the "what the results should be" tab.  Line 2 there has an entry for Level 0. Line 3 has Part = 714-B32801-002 in both column E and column AR - those are not different.

Ah my fault, The ones on line 2 and 3 were included because it has a different rev or qty. I just fixed the workbook again so it should be more accurate.

There's no content from sheet1 in Rows2-4 and 6-7 of the "expected result sheet".  That doesn't match your description.  On row5 the two "part" values are the same, which also doesn't match what you say you want.

There are many rows for "level 1" on both source worksheets - it doesn't make much sense to list all cases where level=1 but column B values don't match between any two rows, so I'm really not getting what you want from this.
